# ng serving problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nodejs, npm, javascript

I've already installed AngularCLI with npm and then I tried serving `ng serve --open` in the terminal. But the terminal showed an empty screen and then nothing happened.
[image: Screenshot of Terminal after serving app]

What can I do to serve my Angular app?

> Problem solved! it's because of user privileges. use `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to have installed is the `ng` command from `ng-common`, which is an emacs-like command-line editor, not the Angular CLI.

Anyway, the Angular CLI is for Angular 2 or newer only, not for the old AngularJS. AngularJS is just a JavaScript library you include in your html, not the whole build framework Angular (2 or newer) provides.

You'd have to serve your project files with a regular web server.

Comment: I'd already installed Angular CLI with the instruction provided by their official website, what I'm taking about is the last step when i want to serve my-App

Comment: If you use AngularJS ("Angular 1") and not Angular (2 or newer), you can not use the Angular CLI. And the screenshot you provided is not the Angular CLI's `ng` command, but what I said in my answer. There is no specific way to serve an AngularJS project, because it's just a simple web page with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, where no preprocessing, transpiling or bundling of the sources is required. You can either try opening the html file directly from the disk in your browser, but that might mess up URL paths, or you need to install any server application.

Comment: I still have that old problem in ubuntu, I install angular 6 and also ng-common and issue is the same as it was before

Comment: You shall **not** install the `ng-common` package. As I said in my answer, this is an editor, and completely unrelated to Angular. Remove it with `sudo apt purge ng-common` to avoid confusion. You must install the correct npm package with `npm install -g @angular/cli`, as described on https://cli.angular.io/.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't about `ng` or `ng-common` hopefully. it was because of `npm install -g @angular/cli`, it must be `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` actually. thanks